# Select row just inserted without using IDENTITY column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a *bigint* PK column which is ***NOT*** an identity column, because I create the number in a function using different numbers. Anyway, I am trying to save this `bigint` number in a parameter `@InvID`, then use this parameter later in the procedure.

`ScopeIdentity()` is not working for me, it saved Null to `@InvID`, I think because the column is not an identity column. Is there anyway to select the record that was just inserted by the procedure without adding an extra ID column to the table?

It would save me a lot of effort and work if there is a direct way to select this record and not adding an id column.

```
insert into Lab_Invoice(iID, iDate, iTotal, iIsPaid, iSource, iCreator, iShiftID, iBalanceAfter, iFileNo, iType)
values (dbo.Get_RI_ID('True'), GETDATE(),
        (select FilePrice from LabSettings), 'False', @source, @user, @shiftID, @b, @fid, 'Open File Invoice');

set @invID = CAST(scope_identity() AS bigint);
```

P.S. `dbo.Get_RI_ID('True')` a function returns a `bigint`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use?

```
set @invId=dbo.Get_RI_ID('True');
 insert into Lab_Invoice(iID,iDate,iTotal,iIsPaid,iSource,iCreator,iShiftID,iBalanceAfter,iFileNo,iType)
values(@invId,GETDATE(),(select FilePrice from LabSettings),'False',@source,@user,@shiftID,@b,@fid,'Open File Invoice');
```

You already know that big id value. Get it before your insert statement then use it later.

Answer (score 0):

one way to get inserted statement value..it is not clear which value you are trying to get,so created some example with dummy data

```
create table #test
(
id int
)

    declare @id table
    (
    id int
    )

    insert into #test
    output inserted.id into @id
    select 1

    select @invID=id from @id
```

Comment: I am trying to Replace this line : set @invID=CAST(scope_identity() AS bigint);
With another way to assign the inserted iID to @InvID. Without using output parameter ,because I'm going to use it in another line in the procedure.

Comment: replace the column data what  you need in place of =id